# Memory usage increase with Ruby 2.1 versus Ruby 2.0 or 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, heroku, ruby-2.1

I recently deployed an upgrade of Ruby from 2.0 to 2.1.5 to my Heroku web application, and I am consistently hitting memory quota errors now, whereas with 2.0 and 1.9 this never happened.  There is a limit of 512MB for a normal Heroku Dyno, and I am running 2 processes with Unicorn, along with one thread with Sidekiq across two dynos.

After reading [Phusion Passenger memory consumption increase from 1.9.3 (system) to 2.1.2 (RVM) on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568467/phusion-passenger-memory-consumption-increase-from-1-9-3-system-to-2-1-2-rvm/24569004), I tried setting the environment variable `RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR` to 0.9 to disable generational garbage collector, and it did improve memory consumption somewhat, but still left me nowhere near what 2.0 or 1.9 consumed.  As memory right now is my primary concern, I would like to see if I can fix this problem with ruby 2.1.x instead of reverting to 2.0.

Here are some graphs demonstrating the problem:

**At just before 2pm, I downgraded to Ruby 2.0.0-p598 to Ruby 2.1.5 and the memory issues were resolved and remained under the limit.**

[image: moving from 2.1.5 to 2.0.0 Heroku]
[image: moving from 2.1.5 to 2.0.0 New Relic]

**Then later, I tried upgrading to Ruby 2.1.5 but setting the environment variable `RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR` to 0.9.  As you can see, the memory usage is slightly better than the original 2.1.5 graph, but still breaches the memory quota.**

[image: moving from 2.0.0 to 2.1.5 with <code>RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR</code> to 0.9 Heroku]
[image: moving from 2.0.0 to 2.1.5 with <code>RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR</code> to 0.9 New Relic]

Comment: very interesting.  I would have thought [this](https://www.omniref.com/blog/blog/2014/11/18/ko1-at-rubyconf-2014-massive-garbage-collection-speedup-in-ruby-2-dot-2/) was related but curious to see what the answer is here.

Comment: Been following the 2.2 release too, but I am concerned that their focus is largely on performance improvements as opposed to memory consumption improvements, so I suspect it won't help much.

Comment: Some early testers reported lower memory footprint due to updated GC in 2.0.0-preview1. You might want to check it out.

Comment: @Lenart, Did you mean 2.2.0-preview1?

Comment: @MatthewO'Riordan that's correct. 2.2 of course. My bad!

Comment: 2 things; 1: Where are you getting these awesome graphs from? 2: Have you considered moving to [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/). I believe that might reduce your memory footprint, but I am not sure. I also see that in some tests Ruby Enterprise Edition appears to have much lower memory footprint (about half in some tests I saw :O)

Answer (score 13):

So the answer is clearly upgrade to Ruby version 2.2.

I am impressed to see that memory usage has actually gone down following the upgrade to 2.2, whereas upgrading to 2.1 was a huge increase in memory consumption.  See the graph below.

[image: Memory usage with 2.2]

On the far left memory consumption on 2.0 sits at around 386mb when under load, whereas with 2.2 it now sits at around 365mb.

Comment: I'm seeing improvements in memory consumption in Ruby 2.2 as well. You should probably mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Is Ruby 2.2 stable with Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Ruby (versions 2.1.x) and its garbage collection. After reading couple of forums/blog posts there seems to be no real solution but to do one of the following:

- downgrade to ruby 2.0 and wait for ruby 2.2 to be released
- use [unicorn worker killer](https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer) to restart unicorn workers once they reach certain amount of memory, preventing Heroku R14 errors
- some suggest tweaking your GC variables (see [here](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/tuning-rgengc-2-1-on-heroku/359/12) and [here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production))

Here's a link to relevant [discussion on ruby-lang](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9607).

Some people also noticed that one source of the problems could be NewRelic's gem so you might want to update/remove it and see if it helps.

*Credits for some of the links and info to guys from upcase.com forum*

Comment: Regarding NewRelic gem issues you can add `aggressive_keepalive: true` to your config. This should help resolve memory problems caused by newrelic gem.

Comment: Thanks @Lenart, those are good suggestions.  I downgraded to 2.0 when I was experiencing this issue, hopefully the 2.2 release will resolve the issue, although based on what I have read, I am not entirely convinced it will.  I will update this post as soon as 2.2 is released.

Comment: I am away at the moment, but will try in the New Year and provide an update here.

Comment: @ari Ruby 2.2 is having the same issues for me

Comment: I've just upgraded my gems & deployed with Ruby 2.2, I will provide an update once I have left it to run for a few hours.