# Does Ruby 2.2 Have Memory Issues on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, heroku

Many people experienced issues with memory usage when switching their Rails app from Ruby 2.0 to Ruby 2.1 on Heroku. For example, see [Memory usage increase with Ruby 2.1 versus Ruby 2.0 or 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102565/memory-usage-increase-with-ruby-2-1-versus-ruby-2-0-or-1-9). Are these issues resolved with Ruby 2.2?

Comment: I tested this yesterday. Our apps performed far worse with 2.2 than 2.1 - in fact our worker instances doubled their memory usage.

Comment: 2.2 worked for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102565/memory-usage-increase-with-ruby-2-1-versus-ruby-2-0-or-1-9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I gave Ruby 2.2 a try with Rails 4.2 and the same memory problems that plagued Ruby 2.1 also occurred. I am switching back to Ruby 2.0. Rails 5 will require Ruby 2.2 and higher so I hope someone will find a way to fix this.

Comment: I had the same issue..with 2.2.1...95% memory usage. Downgrading to 2.0.0

Answer (score 6):

We tried Ruby 2.2.2 on Heroku's Cedar-14 stack, 2X dynos, even reducing Unicorn workers from 5 to 3, and still had memory hover near the 1GB maximum within a few hours of moderate web traffic, and swap size jumped to 200MB - 300MB.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.2-2.3 introduced another bug for multithreaded C-based ruby installations https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-2_2-oom,

basically, if stars align badly the GC turns off :P and with some sites stars align badly couple times a day, we still use Ruby 2.0 and are waiting for 2.3.5 for the fix from the blog to come out

Comment: Did you mean waiting for Ruby 2.3.1? Have you now moved off 2.0?

Comment: Not yet, we're still on 2.0, to be honest I did not even test if something changed

Comment: I was on 2.1.5 but after reading your answer to this rolled-back to 2.0 on our heroku rails app - dramatic improvement in memory usage / total resolution of previous memory errors that required a 6 hourly puma worker killing. Thanks!