# Does Ruby 2.3.1 fix the memory issues that 2.2 exhibited on Heroku Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Does Ruby 2.3.1 (the version Heroku currently supports for Ruby 2.3.X) fix the escalating memory consumption issue seen in Ruby 2.2 when running Rails apps on Heroku?

Many people, us included, found they had to revert from ruby 2.2 back to 2.0 in their Heroku Rails 4 apps due to rapidly escalating memory consumption:

[Does Ruby 2.2 Have Memory Issues on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653207/does-ruby-2-2-have-memory-issues-on-heroku)

so I'm wondering if 2.3.1 is now stable/safe for Heroku Rails apps.