# Is Rails 5 viable on Heroku with Ruby 2.2.2+, or still plagued by R14 errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, heroku

What if any version of Ruby (2.2.2 or higher) runs in production on Heroku without causing R14 (out of memory) errors for Rails 5 apps? And if so, is "GC tuning" now required to get an app stable in production?

I am creating a new Rails app that will run on Heroku. I'd prefer to use Rails 5 **but** it requires Ruby 2.2.2+ and that version of Ruby was a disaster for Rails 4 memory usage on Heroku, for example:
[Does Ruby 2.2 Have Memory Issues on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653207/does-ruby-2-2-have-memory-issues-on-heroku)

As noted in the S.O. thread linked above, Ruby 2.2.2 caused Rails 4.2 apps to run out of memory with R14 errors in a few hours under low load conditions even with half as many unicorn workers. I and other S.O. posters had to downgrade back to Ruby 2.0 to eliminate the R14 errors.

I have been unable to find any reports online indicating whether there is finally some version of Ruby higher than 2.0 that avoids the R14 issues, and allows Rails 5 apps to run stably on Heroku.

Comment: I do have an production app running on Heroku with Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.0 without R14 issues. But my GC is highly customized.

Comment: ErvalhouS, did you have to tune the GC to get it to work reliably, or did it work OK out of the box before the tuning?

Comment: The only way to avoid huge memory peaks in my application is tuning GC, but that was the case even before Rails 5. It doesn't work reliably without it.

Comment: I run mostly without disk swap use, it peaks on some reports pages, where a lot of records are loaded, but GC runs and Swap goes to 0 in few minutes.

Comment: Just for the sake of comparison the application receives between 150 - 600 requests/minute on 2x dyno, with stable 70% memory use